# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([2])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([504, 2]))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a CNN network for classfication (2 labels). It consists of a number of conv3d layers chained together in a list which is then executed in a for loop in my forward function. The model is as follows:

```
(0) : Sequential(
      (0): Dropout3d(p=0.2, inplace=False)
      (1): Conv3d(1, 8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1))
      (2): BatchNorm3d(8, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (3): ELU(alpha=1.0)
      (4): Conv3d(8, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1))
      (5): BatchNorm3d(16, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (6): ELU(alpha=1.0)
    )
(1) : Sequential(
      (0): Dropout3d(p=0.1, inplace=False)
      (1): Conv3d(16, 24, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1))
      (2): BatchNorm3d(24, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (3): ELU(alpha=1.0)
      (4): Conv3d(24, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1))
      (5): BatchNorm3d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (6): ELU(alpha=1.0)
    )
 (2) : Sequential(
      (0): Conv3d(32, 80, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1))
      (1): BatchNorm3d(80, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): ELU(alpha=1.0)
      (3): Conv3d(80, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1))
      (4): BatchNorm3d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (5): ELU(alpha=1.0)
    )
 (3) : Sequential(
      (0): Conv3d(128, 72, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=(1, 1, 1))
      (1): BatchNorm3d(72, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): ELU(alpha=1.0)
      (3): Conv3d(72, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1))
      (4): BatchNorm3d(16, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (5): ELU(alpha=1.0)
    )
  (finallayer) : Conv3d(16, 2, kernel_size=(4, 5, 4), stride=(1, 1, 1))
```

After each sequential block [0-4] we do a max pooling , using this :

```
max_pool3d(x, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
```

The output of the finallayer is then reshaped :

```
x = x.reshape(-1, 2)
```

The dimensions after each sequential and max pooling layer call is shown below:

```
Input dimension before calling forward: torch.Size([2, 1, 182, 218, 182])
#Here, 2 is batch size and 1 is channel. 

Output dimension of (0) convolution layer: [2, 16, 180, 216, 180] 
#printing as list(x.shape)

Output dimension of pool (0) layer : [2, 16, 90, 108, 90]

Output dimension of (1) convolution layer : [2, 32, 88, 106, 88]

Output dimension of pool (1) layer : [2, 32, 44, 53, 44]

Output dimension of (2) convolution layer : [2, 128, 42, 51, 42]

Output dimension of pool (2) layer : [2, 128, 21, 25, 21]

Output dimension of (3) convolution layer : [2, 16, 19, 23, 19]

Output dimension of pool (3) layer : [2, 16, 9, 11, 9]

Dimension before calling finallayer : [2, 16, 9, 11, 9]

Dimension after finallayer but before reshape : [2, 2, 6, 7, 6]

Dimension post reshape : [504, 2]
```

While calling `criterion` which internally calls `binary_cross_entropy_with_logits` of pytorch. I am getting this dimension mismatch.

```
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([2])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([504, 2]))
```

I have looked into similar questions where they have mentioned to use `torch.unsqueeze()` however, I am not sure I can use `unsqueeze` to create 504 rows.

Also, I have cross checked each output layer channel number after each call and have validated it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you're missing a linear module that turns a input feature dimension into the dimension of classes. You shouldn't be reshaping the output of your conv layers this way to have the dimension of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a [fully connected](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) layer that transforms `Batch x Features` into `Batch x Classes`

Add this to your model contructor (Assuming your batch size is = 1)

```
self.fc = nn.Linear(1008, 2)
```

And this to the end of the forward pass :-

```
x = x.reshape(batch_size, -1)
x = self.fc(x)
```

Make sure you scale 1008 by your batch dimension. Ideally you should be able to calculate the dimensionality of the conv output at the end

Comment: Thanks. I will try and update in this thread.

Comment: I've just edited the answer, please check the updated one.